# TypeError when issueing an HTTP GET request in Dart

Tags: http, flutter, dart

Using Dart `http` package, I'm creating a request this way:

```
var response = await http.get('some valid URL', headers: { ... })
```

Sometimes, this raises an exception:

```
_TypeError (type '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic')
```

The whole request block is surrounded by try...catch clause, but for some reason, this exception does not get caught. What is the problem?

Comment: I think it is from your `catch` block. Can you show us that. And check whether your URL is http or https.

Comment: The catch block is nothing fancy - `try { var response = ... } catch(e) { print(e); }`. The URL is plain HTTP.

Comment: Can you check if the url has valid json?

Comment: The URL does return a valid JSON, but at this point in the program it's not decoded.